# Where to get MS SQL Server 2005 Software?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I own a software that uses MS-SQL Server 2005 with a runtime licence. The MS-SQL Server crashed and I need setup files. Where can I get/buy the software. What proof should I provide that I own a runtime licence. (The place that I bought the software dowsn't exist any more)

Comment: What about www.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 0):

As [RC.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180100/rc) suggested: [SQL Server 2005 Downloads on microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb671254.aspx)